# FFMPEG - Concat Videos + Add Audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to pipe some videos into an ffmpeg command which will concat the videos (keeping their audio) and mix a background audio track over the whole thing. I need the video to end when the audio does.

However right now this doesn't work right. The music cuts out after the first video, and ffmpeg doesnt stop encoding when music stops. It seems simple enough but I've been working at this all night, any help would be appreciated.

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -f concat -safe 0 -i pipe: -i "music.mp3" -filter_complex "[1:a]afade=in:0:d=10,volume=0.5[music];[0:a][music]amix=duration=longest[a]" -map "0:v" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -x264-params keyint=120:scenecut=0 -c:a aac -ac 1 -ar 22050 -movflags faststart -r 30 -fflags genpts "%random%.mp4"
```

Comment: The [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) accepts a list of inputs. Yours just has a pipe. It appears to me that you don't need to use the concat demuxer. Also, you should always provide the complete log from your command.

Comment: My pipe is connected to a list of inputs, I didn't see the point in posting a thread with thousands of lines of "file 'file1.mp4' before my command.

Comment: All inputs must have the same attributes and same number and type of streams.